# How do I pass a String to a method accepting Into<&str>?

Tags: rust, clap

I'm trying to pass a `String` to clap's builder methods:

```
extern crate clap; // 2.32.0

use clap::App;

const NAME: &'static str = "example";
const DESC_PART_1: &'static str = "desc";
const DESC_PART_2: &'static str = "ription";

fn main() {
    let description: String = format!("{}{}", DESC_PART_1, DESC_PART_2);
    let matches = App::new(NAME).about(description).get_matches();
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: std::convert::From<std::string::String>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:34
   |
11 |     let matches = App::new(NAME).about(description).get_matches();
   |                                  ^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `&str`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<&str>` for `std::string::String`
```

[Live example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=15667c16c7d853ce4a668dfb453948b6&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018)

I get a similar error if I pass `&description`. I'm struggling to understand the origin of this error and the reasoning behind clap using the signature `pub fn about<S: Into<&'b str>>(self, about: S) -> Self`.

Comment: FWIW, `description.as_ref()` works.

Comment: So it does! Any idea why this works and not `&`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the given (unusual) constraint of `Into<&str>`, the compiler is unable to turn a `String` or a `&String` directly into the requested string slice. There is no such implementation of either `From<String>`, nor `From<&String>`, for a string slice. Conversions from an owned string or string-like value to a slice is usually done through other traits.

Instead, you can:

1. Use [`String::as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html?search=#method.as_str), which always provides `&str`;
2. Call `as_ref()` from the [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait, leading the compiler to choose the implementation `AsRef<str>` for `String`;
3. Or re-borrow the string, thus forcing a conversion to `&str`.

```
let matches = App::new(NAME).about(description.as_str()).get_matches(); // (1)
let matches = App::new(NAME).about(description.as_ref()).get_matches(); // (2)
let matches = App::new(NAME).about(&*description).get_matches(); // (3)
```

Comment: Great :) Any idea why the compiler is unable to convert directly? I'd love to understand fully

Comment: @JMAA Just updated. Basically, this API is a bit unusual to request an `Into<&str>`. There is no such implementation of `From<String>` for a string slice, and the compiler does not coerce `&String` to something that fulfills `Into<&str>` either. Other APIs often choose to take parameters `T: AsRef<str>` or string slices directly, thus avoiding these issues.

Comment: @JMAA I *think* it's possible for the standard library to implement `Into<&str> for &String`; perhaps you could give it a shot and try contributing it!

Comment: @E_net4 I was just leaving an almost identical comment :) The reason why there is no implmentation of `Into<&str> for String` is because `into` consumes self, so it wouldn't be possible for it to return a reference type.

Comment: @PeterHall Right! This would also not be the case for `&String`, but it's not implemented yet. (or at least we think it can be for the time being)